# reading cross domain xml in parse.cloud

Tags: parse-platform

Writing a parse.cloud code to read cross domain xml.
I have tried using jquery-ajax but am stuck with syntactical issue my code is

```
Parse.Cloud.define("read", function(request, response) {

var query = 'http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml&callback=?';

           $.ajax({
                  url: query,
                  type: 'GET',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(s) { 
                  response.success("Success");
                  },
                  error: function(e) 
                  { 
                  response.success("Error "+e)                    
                  }
                  });
});
```

I am getting following error :

> "code":141,"error":"ReferenceError: $ is not defined\n    at main.js:5:20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml',
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    // httpResponse.data will hold the returned object
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
  }
});
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking
https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.HTTPResponse.html

Comment: can you write a simple code to read httpResponse.data object to get xml nodes please. I am totally blank in parse.cloud. Thanks in advance

Comment: pls help me out in this code i m getting the same data each time i m executing even data on the given url is keep updating each day